# SQL Server 2005 : find customers that doesn't order from one year

Tags: if-statement, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to find customers names in a SQL Server 2005 database that don't have any orders, or ask for quotation from one year. I'm trying this but it doesn't work, because it show me only documents older than one year, but show them also if in the current year other documents of the same customers are presents.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ANAGRAFICACF.CODCONTO,
    DSCCONTO1,
    '€ '+LEFT(TOTDOCUMENTO,LEN(TOTDOCUMENTO)-2),
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),DATADOC,6),
    TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC,
    ANAGRAFICACF.PARTITAIVA,
    ANAGRAFICACF.CODFISCALE,
    ANAGRAFICARISERVATICF.NOTE1,
    TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC,
    TESTEDOCUMENTI.CODAGENTE1,
    ANAGRAFICAAGENTI.DSCAGENTE 
FROM
    dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ANAGRAFICACF ON CODCLIFOR = CODCONTO
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.RIGHEDOCUMENTI ON PROGRESSIVO = IDTESTA AND TOTNETTORIGA <> '0'
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.ANAGRAFICARISERVATICF ON CODCLIFOR = ANAGRAFICARISERVATICF.CODCONTO
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.ANAGRAFICAAGENTI ON CODAGENTE = TESTEDOCUMENTI.CODAGENTE1
WHERE  
    (dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = 'ORDER' OR
     dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = 'QUOTATION') 
    AND (dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC < DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()) 

ORDER BY 
    TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC DESC
```

This is

```
CODCONTO | DSCCONTO1 | TOTDOCUMENTO| DATADOC | TIPODOC| CODAGENTE| DSCAGENTE|
---------+-----------+-------------+---------+--------+----------+----------+
C 10395  |CAIO|€ 1048.22    |03 Aug 15  |ORC    |2015-08-03 00:00:00.000    |A     4    |F
C 51282 |SEMPRONIO|€ 2217.41    |03 Aug 15  |PCL    |2015-08-03 00:00:00.000        |NULL
C 10120 |PINCO |€ 689.54    |03 Aug 15  |PCL    |2015-08-03 00:00:00.000    |A     4    |F 
C   746 |TIZIO  |€ 205.45   |03 Aug 15  |ORC    |2015-08-03 00:00:00.000    |A     4    |F
```

SOLUTION (thank you to @scsimon)
Add this where condition, with the NOT IN:

```
    WHERE      dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = 'FVC' AND dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC < DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()) 
               AND TESTEDOCUMENTI.CODCLIFOR NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT TESTEDOCUMENTI.CODCLIFOR
                    FROM dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI  
                    WHERE dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = 'FVC' AND dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC > DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())
                    )

Hope this will help, if someone else will have my request.
```

Comment: Your last where clause seems irrelevant. What happens when you remove it

Comment: Yes is is irrelevant. I obtain the same result, but still wrong result, because I obtain the name of a customer that has orders also in the present year. I need to exclude them.

Comment: Is the order date only based on dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC

Comment: yes only on that and at least the delivery day, but I don't think that is useful to use it.

Comment: Then only using `AND (dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC < DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()) ` should be fine. Can you post a sample data set? Are you seeing dates in TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC that are > 8/1/2015 if you run it today?

Comment: I see order with DATADOC < 2015/08/03, but for example I see one customer called "PINCO" that has ordered also in 2016. So i need to tell to sql to exclude from these result ANAGRAFICACF.CODCONTO and
    DSCCONTO1 if they exist also with DATADOC > 2015/08/03. I will update post with query result

Comment: Ok @BigBlack I think I understand now. If a customer has an order within the last year, exclude them, even if they have an order OLDER than a year. Return only customers who have an order older than a year and no orders within a year. Correct?

Comment: Yes its perfect like that

Comment: how did the solution below work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `NOT EXISTS`. If `ANAGRAFICACF.CODCONTO` is your CustomerNumber then the below should work for you. Since your column names aren't very self-explanatory, change them to what you need if I am incorrect. But, the logic of `NOT EXISTS` is what you want.

**REMOVE:**

```
AND NOT dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE())
```

**ADD:**

```
AND ANAGRAFICACF.CODCONTO NOT IN 
                (SELECT DISTINCTANAGRAFICACF.CODCONTO 
                FROM dbo.ANAGRAFICACF
                INNER JOIN
                  dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI ON CODCLIFOR = CODCONTO
                WHERE 
                  dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DATADOC > DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()))
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

Click [HERE](http://rextester.com/DYDQU66432) to run this code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#agents') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #agents
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#items') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #items

create table #agents (AgentID varchar(2), name varchar(50))
insert into #agents values
('A1','Julius Cesar'),
('B2','Albert Einstien'),
('C3','Frank Thomas')


create table #items (AgentID varchar(2), ItemID int, ItemName varchar(50), DT datetime)
insert into #items (AgentID, ItemID, ItemName, DT) values
--Notice Juliues Cesar has items in the current year, AND older than a year
('A1',1,'Apple','7/1/2015'),
('A1',2,'Pear','7/1/2016'),
('A1',3,'Watermelon','12/1/2015'),
('A1',4,'Grape','1/1/2015'),

--Notice Albert Einstien only has items older than a year

('B2',5,'Car','7/1/2015'),
('B2',6,'Truck','5/1/2015'),
('B2',7,'Van','3/1/2015'),

--Notice Frank Thomas only has items older than a year
('C3',8,'Car','7/1/2014'),
('C3',9,'Truck','5/1/2014'),
('C3',10,'Van','3/1/2014')


Select 
    a.name
    ,i.* 
from 
    #items i
    inner join #agents a on 
    a.AgentID = i.AgentID
where
    --Items that are older than a year
    DT < DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())
    AND i.AgentID NOT IN (select distinct AgentID from #items where dt > DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Can be the right way but like that I obtain a white query result. I dont' understand why...

Comment: If I try the subquery I see results... A strange thing that happen is that, if I modify the subquery to < DATEADD(DAY, -980, GETDATE())) so with < and -980 I see all results like if the subquery isn't present. If I set - 979  I still have blank result. I don't know if this can be related. The first result is 2013-11-28... Maybe that with -980 I overlay this data.

Comment: Without seems your raw data it's hard to trouble shoot but this is the method you want to use.

Comment: I tryed to compare manually data, and they are different... Even If I Only make 2 query one with > and one with < I see different Customer Codes. But when I use the not exist the result is black. There's another commad to use to exclude results?

Comment: @BigBlack I gave you another way using NOT IN. I also provided a sample data set. This should solve your issue so consider up-voting and accepting it as well as the other question i solved for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now it work fine. I've under 15 point so my vote is registered but still not published.

Comment: @BigBlack as the OP you should accept an answer when it's correct. That's by clicking the CHECK under the voting. Do this for all of your questions in the future :)